# How can I get Time Machine to mount a local sparsebundle - error 45

Tags: backup, time-machine, mojave, mount

I'm switching from a local backup disk to a local `.sparsebundle` so that I can easily save the encrypted `.sparsebundle` to remote storage.

The following works:

- Mount the sparse bundle to `/Volumes/foo`
- `tmutil setdestination /Volumes/foo`
- Run backup

The `.sparsebundle` is on an external disk like `/Volumes/bar/foo.sparsebundle`. If I point Time Machine at `bar` as the backup destination, I get the following error:

> Time Machine couldn't complete the backup to "foo".
>   The backup disk image /Volumes/bar/foo.sparsebundle" could not be accessed (error 45).

This same machine is a backup host for other macs on my network. I have compared the format of their `.sparsebundle`s and they seem to be very similar. The local has "Owners: Enabled" while the remotes have "Owners: Disabled" in Disk Utility. When I mount a remote `.sparsebundle` I am the owner of all the files. When I mount the local, they have the same ownership as the source disk.

How can I get Time Machine to automatically mount my local `.sparsebundle`?

Comment: I had a problem where a newly created sparsebundle was actually APFS instead of HFS+ even though I specified HFS+ when creating it. I had to reformat it once it was created, so check that with disk utility, it could be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This one is `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`. My other backups are also case sensitive, but it seems like Time Machine never mounts the `.sparsebundle` so it seems unlikely this is the issue.